# Avoid URL cache-busting parameters with RequireJS for CDN

Tags: requirejs

Is there a way to remove the URL cache busting parameters for external CDN resources?

I want to have cache busting for my library files, but not for external jquery cdn files.
Right now I'm using:`requirejs.config({ urlArgs : "v1.1"});` to have the cache busting.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly the oldest question I've answered so far!

I've created this fiddle to use [RequireJS contexts](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion), but it doesn't seem to work.

The contexts load the modules from the different paths ok, but both calls to `require()` use the cache bust (`urlArgs`) parameter.

So my conclusion would be you can't do what you want to do out-of-the-box.

http://jsfiddle.net/FXSSf/5/

```js
// Fiddle to try and have two RequireJS contexts, one without cache bust for CDN and one with cache bust for 'our' files
// See http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion

// ensure that $ is invalid to begin with
var $ = null;

var cdnRequire = require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1"
    },
    urlArgs: ""
});

var ourRequire = require.config({
    baseUrl: "https://gist.github.com/gitgrimbo/5130393/raw/b9402d4dfb00ff0ad3211f30681bb6d0411e4295",
    urlArgs: "ourRequire-" + new Date().getTime()
});

// cdnRequire should *not* use cache bust parameter
cdnRequire(["jquery"], function ($) {
    alert($.fn.jquery);
    // ourRequire *should* use cache bust parameter
    ourRequire(["gistfile1"], function (myModule) {
        alert(myModule);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul for the reply. I'm still looking for a solution for this problem. It's such a common use case that I can't believe it's not being implemented in the requirejs